# django store text editor input value

Tags: python, html, mysql, django, twitter-bootstrap

6 and mysql as my database. I used bootstrap rich text editor. I want to store the values given in text editor(both content and images uploaded). I have searched but I didn't get any related solution.

my template

```
{% extends "quorum/base_quorum.html" %}
{% block extraheadfrmreg %}
<link href="{{STATIC_URL}}bootstrap-rte/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css">
  .content{
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
}


#editor {
  max-height: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: white;
  border-collapse: separate; 
  border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); 
  padding: 10px; 
  box-sizing: content-box; 
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0745098) 0px 1px 1px 0px inset; 
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0745098) 0px 1px 1px 0px inset;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px; border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px; border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  overflow: auto;
  outline: none;
}

#voiceBtn {
  width: 20px;
  color: transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
  transform: scale(2.0, 2.0);
  -webkit-transform: scale(2.0, 2.0);
  -moz-transform: scale(2.0, 2.0);
  border: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}

div[data-role="editor-toolbar"] {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.dropdown-menu a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>

{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<script language="javascript">
function loadVal(){
  desc = $("#editor").html();
  document.form1.desc.value = desc;
}

</script>
<form method="POST" name="form1" action="#" onsubmit="loadVal();">

<div class="content">

<div id="alerts"></div>
    <div class="btn-toolbar" data-role="editor-toolbar" data-target="#editor">
      <div class="btn-group">
        <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Font"><i class="icon-font"></i><b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          </ul>
        </div>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Font Size"><i class="icon-text-height"></i>&nbsp;<b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a data-edit="fontSize 5"><font size="5">Huge</font></a></li>
          <li><a data-edit="fontSize 3"><font size="3">Normal</font></a></li>
          <li><a data-edit="fontSize 1"><font size="1">Small</font></a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <a class="btn" data-edit="bold" title="Bold (Ctrl/Cmd+B)"><i class="icon-bold"></i></a>
        <a class="btn" data-edit="italic" title="Italic (Ctrl/Cmd+I)"><i class="icon-italic"></i></a>
        <a class="btn" data-edit="strikethrough" title="Strikethrough"><i class="icon-strikethrough"></i></a>
        <a class="btn" data-edit="underline" title="Underline (Ctrl/Cmd+U)"><i class="icon-underline"></i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <a class="btn" data-edit="insertunorderedlist" title="Bullet list"><i class="icon-list-ul"></i></a>
        <a class="btn" data-edit="insertorderedlist" title="Number list"><i class="icon-list-ol"></i></a>
        <a class="btn" data-edit="outdent" title="Reduce indent (Shift+Tab)"><i class="icon-indent-left"></i></a>
        <a class="btn" data-edit="indent" title="Indent (Tab)"><i class="icon-indent-right"></i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <a class="btn" data-edit="justifyleft" title="Align Left (Ctrl/Cmd+L)"><i class="icon-align-left"></i></a>
        <a class="btn" data-edit="justifycenter" title="Center (Ctrl/Cmd+E)"><i class="icon-align-center"></i></a>
        <a class="btn" data-edit="justifyright" title="Align Right (Ctrl/Cmd+R)"><i class="icon-align-right"></i></a>
        <a class="btn" data-edit="justifyfull" title="Justify (Ctrl/Cmd+J)"><i class="icon-align-justify"></i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group">
      <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Hyperlink"><i class="icon-link"></i></a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu input-append">
          <input class="span2" placeholder="URL" type="text" data-edit="createLink"/>
          <button class="btn" type="button">Add</button>
        </div>
        <a class="btn" data-edit="unlink" title="Remove Hyperlink"><i class="icon-cut"></i></a>

      </div>

      <div class="btn-group" id="imagediv">
        <a class="btn" title="Insert picture (or just drag & drop)" id="pictureBtn"><i class="icon-picture"></i></a>
        <input type="file" name="image" data-role="magic-overlay" data-target="#pictureBtn" data-edit="insertImage" />
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <a class="btn" data-edit="undo" title="Undo (Ctrl/Cmd+Z)"><i class="icon-undo"></i></a>
        <a class="btn" data-edit="redo" title="Redo (Ctrl/Cmd+Y)"><i class="icon-repeat"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="editor"> Enter your text here.. </div>

<textarea rows="2" name="desc" cols="20" style="display:none; " > Enter your text here.. </textarea>
{% endblock %}
{% block extrajavascript %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{STATIC_URL}}bootstrap-rte/js/bootstrap-wysiwyg.js"></script> 
<script src="{{STATIC_URL}}bootstrap-rte/external/jquery.hotkeys.js"></script>
<script src="{{STATIC_URL}}bootstrap-rte/external/google-code-prettify/prettify.js"></script>
<script src="{{STATIC_URL}}bootstrap-rte/js/bootstrap-wysiwyg.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    function initToolbarBootstrapBindings() {
      var fonts = ['Serif', 'Sans', 'Arial', 'Arial Black', 'Courier', 
            'Courier New', 'Comic Sans MS', 'Helvetica', 'Impact', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', 'Tahoma', 'Times',
            'Times New Roman', 'Verdana'],
            fontTarget = $('[title=Font]').siblings('.dropdown-menu');
      $.each(fonts, function (idx, fontName) {
          fontTarget.append($('<li><a data-edit="fontName ' + fontName +'" style="font-family:\''+ fontName +'\'">'+fontName + '</a></li>'));
      });
      $('a[title]').tooltip({container:'body'});
      $('.dropdown-menu input').click(function() {return false;})
        .change(function () {$(this).parent('.dropdown-menu').siblings('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('toggle');})
        .keydown('esc', function () {this.value='';$(this).change();});

      $('[data-role=magic-overlay]').each(function () { 
        var overlay = $(this), target = $(overlay.data('target')); 
        overlay.css('opacity', 0).css('position', 'absolute').offset(target.offset()).width(target.outerWidth()).height(target.outerHeight());
      });
      if ("onwebkitspeechchange"  in document.createElement("input")) {
        var editorOffset = $('#editor').offset();
        $('#voiceBtn').css('position','absolute').offset({top: editorOffset.top, left: editorOffset.left+$('#editor').innerWidth()-35});
      } else {
        $('#voiceBtn').hide();
      }
  };
  function showErrorAlert (reason, detail) {
    var msg='';
    if (reason==='unsupported-file-type') { msg = "Unsupported format " +detail; }
    else {
      console.log("error uploading file", reason, detail);
    }
    $('<div class="alert"> <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>'+ 
     '<strong>File upload error</strong> '+msg+' </div>').prependTo('#alerts');
  };
    initToolbarBootstrapBindings();  
  $('#editor').wysiwyg({ fileUploadError: showErrorAlert} );
    window.prettyPrint && prettyPrint();
  });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
def txtedit(request):
    from django.templatetags.static import static
    url=static('bootstrap.css')
    print url
    return render(request,"quorum/textarea.html")
```

Could anyone please help me out..

Answer (score 0):

Here saving the whole image and text in the mysql DB is not a good solution.

You need to save the images/files in your media folder and save the path along with other text in the DB.

You can use the django-ckeditor for this: https://github.com/shaunsephton/django-ckeditor.

It will save what you need in the db and the media file separately.

You just need to call the field in model.

```
from django.db import models
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField

class Post(models.Model):
    content = RichTextField()
```

Comment: ya thanks Ranju but I have to do it with mysql and the editor is rich text editor.. Could you give any suggesstions

Answer (score 0):

Your `views.py` is too short. It even doesn't handle POST request. Or had your question been unintentionally truncated.